# Not able to connect to non-default oracle database after reboot

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation, connectivity

I have installed Oracle 11g r2 on Centos. On initial setup it installed database named INFA for me.I setup listener.ora and tnsnames.ora for `INFA` and on reboots all I had to do was run `lsnrctl start` command the instance by using following command `sqlplus /as sysdba` and `SQL>startup`.Now I needed another database I created another database using dbca as that was recommended by oracle(I think I should have used sql). New database named `hayer_test` with SID `hayertest`was installed in same directory as `INFA` and it was up and running after install(before reboot).Now I rebooted the OS and when I did the steps I used to do only `INFA` database came up.Not sure how to bring this second database up.

**Ok on more investigating I found that my init.ora has all description of only one database and I have to sp files now I have no idea how I should tell oracle to use both spfiles and start the instance for both databases.So I guess when I do `sql>startup` it looks at spfile$ORACLE_SID.ora and as I have only set up one $ORACLE_SID it only starts one database.Please help me set up multiple SID's.**

Here the error I get when I try to connect now.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jun 26 11:28:45 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system@hayer_test
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

My tnsnames.ora and listener.ora file contains this:
listener.ora:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hayer)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle

tnsname.ora:

```
HAYER_TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hayer)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = hayer_test)
    )
  )

INFA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hayer)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = infa)
    )
  )
```

`lsnrctl status` command gives me following result :

```
    LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-JUN-2014 11:25:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                27-JUN-2014 11:24:34
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 38 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/hayer/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hayer)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "infa" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "infa", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "infaXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "infa", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

The command completed successfully

I registered the database with listener when I installed database first time.

Ran `SQL> show parameter local_list;` and got this result :

```
NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener               string
```

The following query was ran `ps -fe|grep pmon` gives following result.

```
oracle   21012     1  0 08:44 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_infa
oracle   21367 21353  0 08:46 pts/1    00:00:00 grep pmon
```

The configuration files found by `ls -l /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/*HAYER*` showed following result.

```
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 24 Jun 26 16:33 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/lkHAYER_TE
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 24 Jun 26 16:33 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/lkHAYER_TEST
```

The command completed successfullyI am new to this and learning please help.Also if anyone can recommend most efficient way of creating databases in Oracle(dbca or sql query).

Comment: On your second question, I would say to use the DBCA until you get more experienced and comfortable with the command line.

Comment: Set the environment for your other database using $. oraenv (note the dot) and fire up the thing.

Comment: The error message of sqlplus says that the listnener doew not know a service HAYER_TEST. If you ask the listener directly using lsnrctl you can see that the listner  does not know a service HAYER_TEST. 1)Do you have an instance HAYERTEST with a service called HAYER_TEST. 2)Why does the definition of tnsname HAYER_TEST contain a service_name and a sid? 3) can you show us the output of the following query: select 'Service' "Type", NETWORK_NAME "Name" from dba_services where NETWORK_NAME is not null 
union all select 'Instance',sys_context('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') from dual ;

Comment: sorry, I see now that you wrote you cannot start your database. so my previous tests are meaningless because you already have not database named HAYERTEST.

Comment: @miracle173 I have reinstalled oracle 11g setup listener on 1521 port then create second database was connected when created but after reboot same thing.Also when I installed I set it up as single instance database not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: 1. check which databases are running `ps -fe|grep pmon` 2. check if there are the appropriate configuration files `ls -l /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/*HAYER*` and show us the output

Comment: @miracle173 I have updated the question with the results you asked for

Comment: @miracle173 I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the listener (the software that listens on the network for database connection attempts) doesn't know that your DB exists.

Normally, when you start up an Oracle 11g DB, it'll automatically "register" with the listener within 60 seconds or so (I believe it's background process PMON responsible for this).  You can force a listener registration by connecting as sysdba on the local machine - e.g.:

> `SHELL> sqlplus / as sysdba`

Then typing:

> `SQL> ALTER DATABASE REGISTER;`

This will tell the database to register with the listener.

However - this relies on the database knowing how to talk to the listener!  Because your listener is listening on port 1522, so you'll need to explicitly tell your database where to find it:

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/listenercfg.htm#NETAG1154 ("Registering Information with a Local Listener")

For a real-world example, see:

http://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/exploring-the-local_listener-parameter/

As to whether you should use DBCA or the query... it's up to you.  DBCA is by far the simpler, however it also hides the details away.  My preference is to use DBCA to generate a set of scripts which I then peruse and alter as appropriate.

Comment: Summer I have already registered the database when I installed database first time.I have edited question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tnsnames.ora, the output from lsnrctl status and the command you're entering, there is a mismatch:

You are trying to connect using `system@hayer_test`

Your tnsnames.ora is set with this for the alias `hayer_test`:

`HAYER_TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hayer)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = hayer_test)
      (SID = hayertest)
    )
  )`

Yet there is nothing in the output of your `lsnrctl status` to indicate that that the listener knows about a database with SID `hayertest` or having a service name called `hayer_test`.

You should be able to connect using the command `sqlplus system@orcl`.  Your listener knows about database `orcl`, and your tnsnames.ora has an alias to connect to a database called `orcl`.

Comment: @PhilSummer Connecting to ORCL is not a problem how do I connect to other database I created and if other database is down how do I bring it up

Comment: I have reinstalled oracle 11g setup listener on 1521 port then create second database was connected when created but after reboot same thing.